# Limit carries with e proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x_n} = e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n} = e^x$.

My attempt:

Begin by considering $|e^{x_n} - e^x|$:

For $k > 0$:

$$|e^{x_n} - e^x| = e^x|e^{x_n - x} - 1| < e^x|e^{k} - 1| < e^{x + k}$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$

$$|x_n - x| < \ln(\epsilon) - x$$

$$|e^{x_n} - e^x| = e^x|e^{x_n - x} - 1| < e^x|e^{\ln(\epsilon) - x} - 1|< e^{x + \ln(\epsilon) - x} = \epsilon$$

Then by definition of the limit, $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x_n} = e^x$.

Is this proof correct? If not or even if so, can someone show me a formal one? Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Just a comment: the $k$ chosen in the beginning depends on $n$.

Comment: In the context of metric spaces, continuous functions map convergent sequences onto convergent sequences.

Comment: This follows from continuity of $e^x$. Your proof has many flaws. How do you know $k>0$? The expression $\log\epsilon - x$ can be negative when $\epsilon$ is small. The definition of limit is not about symbol shunting. Please try to understand the meaning of the definition and then apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn a few properties of exponential function. A key inequality satisfied by exponential function is $$e^t\geq 1+t\tag{1}$$ Replace $t$ with $-t$ and assuming $t\in(0,1)$ to get $$e^t\leq \frac{1}{1-t}$$ or $$e^t-1\leq \frac{t} {1-t}<2t\tag{2}$$ if $0<t<1/2$.

Further we have $$|e^{-t} -1|=1-e^{-t}=\frac{e^t-1}{e^t}<e^t-1\tag{3}$$ and thus it follows from $(2),(3)$ that $$|e^t-1|\leq 2|t|\tag{4}$$ if $|t|<1/2$ and equality holds only if $t=0$.

Now consider the expression $$|e^{x_n} - e^x|=e^x|e^{x_n-x} - 1|\leq 2e^x|x_n-x|\tag{5}$$ via $(4)$ provided that $|x_n-x|<1/2$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and then we can find an  integer $N>0$ such that $$|x_n-x|<\min\left(\frac{\epsilon} {2e^x},\frac{1}{2}\right) $$ whenever $n\geq N$. Now from $(5)$ it follows that $|e^{x_n} - e^x|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$.